# Is it grammatically correct to omit "is" in the following sentence? Is it correct in formal speech?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is it grammatically correct to omit "is" in the following sentence? Is it correct in formal speech?

> The Soviet Union is the largest land power, China the greatest
>   land-sea compound country and the United States the biggest sea power.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is grammatical. It is a form of ellipsis called [gapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapping).

Comment: Doesn't _gapping_ require the omitted word to be used once, at least.

Comment: In this case it is, no? "The Soviet Union **is** the largest land power..."

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I thought the OP was asking if _that_ "is" could be removed too. And the answer would be no.

Comment: @Urbycoz An excellent illustration of the inverse correlation between deletion and clarity.

Comment: Ah, your interpretation may well be correct.

Comment: It certainly is correct. There's [a famous paper by Haj Ross](http://babel.ucsc.edu/~hank/Ross_Gapping.pdf) about how gapping can be used to distinguish right-branching verb-initial languages like English (which gap to the right: _Bill ordered lamb, and Mary sushi_) from left-branching languages like Japanese (which gap to the left: _Bill lamb, and Mary sushi ordered_).